# How to check which UIViewController is active from AppDelegate (After push)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to check which UIViewController scene that is active in code?

I have a push notification coming in to the app, and want to do different things depending on what view the user is in, something like this:

AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
    if (tableViewController == active) 
       //get data from server
    else if (detailedViewController == active) 
        //Get Image from server
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post a local notification:

```
  [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"foo" object:whatever];
```

and have all of the appropriate viewControllers watch for it:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(handleFoo:) 
                                             name:@"foo" 
                                           object:nil];
```

The viewControllers would add or remove Observers as necesary.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( _viewController.isViewLoaded == YES)
{
    NSLog(@"Yes");

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"No");
}
```

Hope, this will help you...

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you used some contaneir view controller. If you are using a `UITabBarController` you could just ask itself for its:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) UIViewController *selectedViewController
```

or its:

```
@property(nonatomic) NSUInteger selectedIndex
```

If you are using a `UINavigationController`:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIViewController *visibleViewController
```

If you prefer a fine grained control over containers you could make your Appdelegate to conform to the respective delegate protocols: `UITabbarControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate`